# Python : getting class type only?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, types

In Python, if I want to get only the variable type when using the command print, how do I do it?

Right now I get `<class 'float'>` but I want `'float'`.

ex.:

```
a = float("4.67")
b = type(a)
print(b)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `.__name__` attribute for this:

```
>>> a = float("4.67")
>>> b = type(a)
>>> b.__name__
'float'
>>>
```

Comment: >> you may also just do >> b

Comment: @ShikharDua - No, he wants the name.  Doing just `>> b` yields `<class 'float'>`.

Comment: Actually, I did using python and Ipython both. Former gives <class 'float'> latter yields 'float'